# Performance of JAXB vs BufferedWriter for Java Object Marshalling

Tags: java, xml, performance, xml-parsing, jaxb

I am working with this legacy system which exports (marshals) huge amount of java objects to an xml file. Because of the volume of the data, it takes nearly 14 hours for this process and we have to optimize this process.

Write now XML tags are created manually and written to the file with a  BufferedWriter that uses FileWriter. Following is a snippet from the current implementation:

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    try
    {
      bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file), 81920);
      writeHeader(bufferedWriter);
      writeNewLine(bufferedWriter);
      writeRootStartTag(bufferedWriter);

      for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
      {
        String user = users[i];
        if (user!=null && user.trim().length()>0)
        {
          String[] xmlForUser = getXMLDataForUser(user, startDate, endDate);
          if(xmlForUser!=null && xmlForUser.length>0)
          {
            for (int j = 0; j < xmlForUser.length; j++)
            {
              String xml = xmlForUser[j];
              write(xml, bufferedWriter);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      writeRootCloseTag(bufferedWriter);
    }
```

- **Would there be a noticeable performance improvement If I go with JAXB to Marshal java objects instead of BufferedWriter approach.**

(Please note any performance gain in Unmarshalling XML files with JAXB is not relevant to the System as another System is used for this. Please also note that I cannot use any 3rd party libraries for this given the fact that the company has strict regulations against 3rd party libraries.)

Comment: While XML nor Java Serialization are known for their speed they still wouldn't take 14 hours unless you have an extra-ordinary amount of data.  You can write a TB or more data in that time. I suspect your bottle neck is not in your XML generation so changing it won't help.  If you are writing multiple TB of data, try writing less data, and reducing repetition.

Comment: Are you really using `String[]`? How are they created? How long is `String[] users`? What is the average/minimum/maximum length of `String[] xmlForUser`? How is `write(String,BufferedWriter)` implemented? Did you ever try running your program while writing to `/dev/null` (or `nil` in Windows)? - Anway, a test using JAXB is not difficult to rig up if your POJOs aren't too far from Java Beans.

Comment: Do you have all of your data as an object tree in memory? How huge is "huge"? Did you ever consider creating the XML in chunks, n users at a time? Concatenating equally structured XML files is simple.